# Mount tv above fireplace

Tags: mount

Need to mount 50”tv above fireplace. However there are no studs or furring strips the drywall appears to have been glued to the chimney/ cement board? The fireplace was wood but has been converted to gas. How do I mount the tv without compromising the chimney

Comment: Step one. Put a portable/adjustable shelf there, set the TV at the height you intend to mount it, see if you REALLY want it in what is typically one of the [worst/least comfortable to watch/too hot for the electronics when the fire is on] places to mount a TV.

Comment: The joke is ugliest pictures go on top of the fireplace because nobody looks up there.

Comment: I agree with all the advice about why TVs above fire places are bad.  But realistically, very few people have living rooms with enough room to arrange furniture with multiple focal points for a TV and a fire place, and very few people have separate spaces for these activities.  There's a reason this horrible practice has become a fad, it's not going away soon, and this isn't the Human Factors Stack.   We can advise against it but also advise how to do it safely.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the many questions about mounting a TV over a fireplace that have been posted here. You will find many of them totally discourage doing what you plan. Many answered by me as well. Just do not do it. Your mounting problems will no longer exist.

Rather than reiterate the reasons for not doing this please read the other posts (and some of my answers). In the end you will be glad you did.

Answer (score 1):

First read the other comments and answers that urge you to find a better place for your TV.   Really, go read them.  Stop reading this.

Still here?   You're mounting to brick.  Just go to youtube or a DIY book and read about how to drill and mount heavy objects in brick.  Nothing special about a TV but since it's a chimney, don't drill all the way through into the flue and don't use plastic plugs.